# Trouble initializing Nested Generics

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, type-constraints

I'm trying to create a class structure that has one class with a generic type (with a type constraint), that is used as a generic type constraint for another generic class. As soon as I try to subclass the first type constraint class, that subclass is no longer usable to init the second generic class (but works fine for the first). Here is a simplified code sample:

```
class DataClass {
    var value: Int
    required init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Thing: DataClass {
    required init(value: Int) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

class ThingWrapper<ThingDataType: Thing>: DataClass {
    var thing: ThingDataType
    required init(value: Int) {
        thing = ThingDataType(value: value)
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

class ThingWrapperList<ThingWrapperType: ThingWrapper<Thing>>: DataClass {
    var things: [ThingWrapperType]
    required init(value: Int) {
        things = [ThingWrapperType]()
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}
```

These work fine:

```
var thingWrapper = ThingWrapper<Thing>(value: 42)
var thingWrapperList = ThingWrapperList<ThingWrapper<Thing>>(value: 42)
```

As does this:

```
class NewThing: Thing {
    required init(value: Int) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

var newThingWrapper = ThingWrapper<NewThing>(value: 42)
```

But this generates an error:

```
var newThingWrapperList = ThingWrapperList<ThingWrapper<NewThing>>(value: 42)
Error: 'ThingWrapperList' requires that 'ThingWrapper<NewThing>' inherit from 'ThingWrapper<Thing>'
```

So can I not use a subclass of the inner type generic constraint? I can probably solve this by getting rid of the "ThingWrapper" class, but I was trying to mimic my JSON format, and now I'm mostly curious what I am doing wrong.

Comment: i think you come from java ;) - less inheritance - maybe more protocols.

Comment: but why not just plain structs?

Comment: you have a sample of your json format where you need this much generics?

Comment: Maybe something more protocol oriented would be better, but this still seems like should work. Any ideas why it doesn't?

Comment: i don't have: i got this `class ThingWrapperList<K: Thing, T: ThingWrapper<K>>: DataClass {` working in playground - no syntax complients - but on run it crash the compiler :(

Comment: how is the structure of you json - can you post a snippet? maybe you don't need so much generics

Comment: in ThingWrapperList the Thing class was `hardwired` and not as generic. i changed it to a generic with K - but somehow the compiler don't like it

Comment: if i write it wrong then the compiler complain: `var newThingWrapperList = ThingWrapperList<NewThing, ThingWrapper<Thing>>(value: 42)` -> `error: 'ThingWrapperList' requires that 'ThingWrapper<Thing>' inherit from 'ThingWrapper<NewThing>'`

Comment: and this additional note: `note: requirement specified as 'T' : 'ThingWrapper<K>' [with K = NewThing, T = ThingWrapper<Thing>]
class ThingWrapperList<K: Thing, T: ThingWrapper<K>>: DataClass {`

Comment: i can write this without the playground give me no error: `var newThingWrapperList = ThingWrapperList<NewThing, ThingWrapper<NewThing>>(value: 42)`

Comment: filed my first bug to apple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by the current implementation of Swift because it doesn't (yet) support covariance or contravariance in generics, which means you need an exact match in the specializing type.

We can try to simplify this with an even smaller example. Let's assume that we have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A1 {}
class A2: A1 {}
class B1<T: A1> {}
class B2<T: A1>: B1<T> {}
```

We can examine the rules Swift enforces:

```
// These first 3 assignments compile correctly:
let a: A1 = A2()           // because A2 inherits from A1
let b: B1<A1> = B2<A1>()   // because B2 inherits from B1 and A1 == A1
let b2: B1<A2> = B2<A2>()  // because B2 inherits from B1 and A2 == A2

// The next 2 assignments do not compile in current Swift
// due to the lack of covariant generics
let b3: B1<A1> = B1<A2>()  // cannot convert value of type 'B1<A2>' to specified type 'B1<A1>'
let b4: B1<A1> = B2<A2>()  // cannot convert value of type 'B2<A2>' to specified type 'B1<A1>'
```

To replicate your issue, we need to add another layer, so let's create a function:

```
func C<T: A1>(_ arg: B1<T>) {}

C(B1<A1>())
C(B1<A2>())
C(B2<A1>())
C(B2<A2>())
```

This all compiles successfully, because we have added another generic parameter to handle the required specialization, instead of trying to rely on covariance.

In summary, to express your class heirarchy in Swift, you need to add another generic parameter to `ThingWrapperList`:

```
class ThingWrapperList<ThingDataType, ThingWrapperType: ThingWrapper<ThingDataType>>: DataClass
```

In this declaration, `ThingWrapperList` is generic over `ThingWrapperType` **and** `ThingDataType`, so you can specialize it with either `Thing` or `NewThing`.